# What are these programs? Who installed them? How to remove them?

Tags: macos, applications

I have some strange programs installed on my mac. I have not installed them myself. Or they might have been installed with other programs.

How to uninstall them? They do not appear on my Applications folder.

- Blinker
- Font Proofer X
- FTXcode
- FTXviewer
- KerxTester
- MorxTester
- UniCharter

[image]

Comment: How long have these apps been there? What apps have you installed recently?

Comment: I don't know 

Comment: _I'm not sure whether this will solve the problem, but it could help with some identification:_ Search for one (or some) of these apps on Spotlight. If they aren't found there, it means they could be hiding in Library. In such case, open up Library and try searching for it in there.

Comment: Try an antivirus scan from the likes of BitDefender or Avast (both are free)?

Comment: I found them inside Applications/FontTools I scanned them with AVG AntiVirus. Nothing detected. But I am still looking to know what are they and who installed them.

Comment: Ok, I found what are they :) They are from apple developer's download site. I may have them installed when I updated my Xcode to 8.1 they are called Font Tools for Xcode

Comment: I had the exact same reaction when I saw these apps in my launcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these are part of Apple's font tools provided with their Developer Stuff.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't answer where the applications came from or who installed them, you can easily locate an application by holding the command key and clicking on its icon. This will open finder and highlight the application for you.